# -[Loans town]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c05e630 2016-02-24

Tags: objective-c

How to access town value from main array? My program is crashed on accessing town values.

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(i=0;i<loanArray.count;i++)
     {
         Loans *loanObj = [[Loans alloc]init];
         loanObj.dictLoan = [loanArray objectAtIndex:i];
         loanObj.funded_amount = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
         loanObj.name = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"name"];
         loanObj.status = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"status"];
         loanObj.basket_amount = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"basket_amount"];
         loanObj.activity = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"activity"];
         loanObj.sector = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"sector"];
         loanObj.use = [loanObj.dictLoan objectForKey:@"use"];
         Location *locObj = [[Location alloc]init];
         locObj.country_code = [locObj.dictLocation objectForKey:@"country_code"];
         locObj.country = [locObj.dictLocation objectForKey:@"country"];
         locObj.town = [locObj.dictLocation objectForKey:@"town"];
         loanObj.propertyLocation=locObj;
         [mainArray addObject:loanObj];

     }
           NSLog(@"\n Arr = %@",((Location*)((Loans*)[mainArray objectAtIndex:0])).town);//Crashed Program Here..
```

Comment: `town` isn't a property of the object you're putting into the array.  You correctly access it when you create the object; why don't you just do the same thing you do literally 4 lines up from the `NSLog()` statement?

Comment: So How to access that town ? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

```
            NSLog(@"\n Arr = %@",((Location*)((Loans*)[mainArray objectAtIndex:0])).propertyLocation.town);
```

Comment: Arr = (null)
 value is null from your answer .What is the correct way anybody tell me why it takes null always ?

Comment: @SharadPatil This answer fixes your question.  Why your location is NULL is because your input data is not what you expect.